# Преобразовать массив строк в массив лонгов

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlet

Всем привет. Есть jsp страница, с которой я получаю выделенные checkbox- ом id. Они добавляются в массив String. Вопрос - как мне преобразовать этот массив строк в массив лонгов (Нужен именно long)

String[] ids = req.getParameterValues("id");

Comment: Long[]longIds = Arrays.stream(stringIds).map(Long::valueOf).toArray(Long[]::new);

Answer (score 1):

Для Java 8 вам уже привели пример в комментах. Вот пример для версии Java ниже 8

```
String[] ids = req.getParameterValues("id");
Long[] longIds = new Long[ids.length];
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        longIds[i] = Long.valueOf(ids[i].trim());
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
```